# In Google Colab, I created a file with Pickle Library but I can't find it in Google Drive

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

```
#Saving the best model with Pickle (Neural %83.43)
import pickle
pickle.dump(classifier, open("NeuralNews", 'wb'))

loading = pickle.load(open("NeuralNews", 'rb'))
predictionPickleNeural = loading.predict(testResult2)

predictionPickleNeural = (predictionPickleNeural > 0.5)

acScorePickleNeural = 
accuracy_score(lb.fit_transform(testDataForComparison), 
predictionPickleNeural)
print("Accuracy Pickle Neural : " + str(acScorePickleNeural))
```

I can't find the 'Neural News' file that I created on Google Drive.

Is there a way to find out where it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its inside the current directory of Google Cloud VM. You can try:

```
import os
os.listdir('.')
```

If you get some output like,

```
['.config', 'sample_data']
```

then you can even get listing by issuing the command like below,

```
!ls sample_data
```

to look inside the `sample_data` folder. Anyway, you can upload/save it to your Google drive or download it to your local machine also.

Comment: Is there a way to copy or download these files present in `sample_data` ?